# How to deploy plugin as a folder in Eclipse?

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-rcp

I want to deploy the plugin that I have created as a folder.

I currently deploy the plugin like this: right click on project -> export -> plug-in development -> deployable plug-ins and fragments -> finish

The problem is that the plug-in is deployed as a jar file even if  the option : package plug-in as individual JAR archive is unchecked.

How to deploy the plugin in a folder form, beacause I need to put that folder in eclipse in order for the plug-in to work ?

Comment: A plugin does not need to be a folder to work unless you have special requirements

Comment: I have special requirements, it should have a certain name type and the classes of the plugin should be in a folder, not in a package, in order for the plugin to work

Comment: That is very unusual. Nearly everything can be done from a jar. But if you want a folder you need to use a [Feature Project](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseFeatureProject/article.html), you can specify that the plugin is expanded during install in the feature.

Comment: Do you know if there's a possibility to include all the required dependencies in the folder or jar file automatically ?

Comment: That depends what you mean by dependencies. Please expand the question.

Comment: I mean all the plugins required by my plugin

Comment: If they are not plugins you wrote you should not include them. Eclipse will resolve these during the install.

Comment: I meant that my plugin is exported as jar file and I want it as a directory. I want to include all the plugins that are used by my plugin (like ui plugin ) in that directory of my plugin, but I want this to be done automatically, I don't want to include them by myself in the classpath

Comment: You can't include other plugins directly in your plugin. You can use a Feature project to create a feature containing multiple plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDE supports the new **Eclipse-BundleShape** header. This header simply has two values, “dir” or “jar,” which specify how the bundle should be packaged.

Check [this blog](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/01/20/tip-eclipse-bundleshape/).

Answer (score 0):

- copy them into the root foder of Eclipse, which already contains
  features and plugins
     restart Eclipse, then can see your installed plugin's settings in Window -> Preferences enter image description here